# Can we add docker support into the winform application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, winforms

I want to containerize a Dotnet Winform application so that I can interact with it through the IP. The application is using System.Windows.Forms. If possible, how can I add docker support into it?

Comment: and how will you interact a winform application running inside container ?

Comment: Through API for now.

Comment: i hope you understand what you are saying. you said winform app and now you are saying through API. be clear what you want.

Comment: Sorry I mean through command line or network.

Comment: Is it possible to host that app using .NET Framework Runtime image?

Comment: yes, if you want to containerize the .net framework app. you can surly do using windows container.

Comment: for that I need to add the application_name.dll file from the bin/debug folder as an EntryPoint right? Into the dockerfile?

Comment: It sounds like you need to refactor your application into at least two parts: 1) a service that exposes your APIs which can run in a container, 2) a Winforms UI that communicates with the API. The Winforms portion of the app would not run in a container.